# Is there a proof that no rational number splits the octave equally?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, physics, mathematical-physics, music-theory

In music circles, when the topic of tuning comes up, it is said that there is no rational number that splits the octave (the interval between a musical pitch and another with double its frequency, for example 440 Hz and 880 Hz) equally, but I have never seen a proof for this, so I wonder if it has been proven, or just universally accepted. Is it maybe that it's too simple to write down and it's expected that one can just do it themselves? I have only finished high school maths (SQA Advanced Higher mathematics) so I haven't got any experience constructing proofs, otherwise I would try it myself.

Comment: Are you familiar with any mathematical expressions that are connected to 'octave'? If so, can you also write those in the question?

Comment: [Why it's impossible to tune a piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Hqm0dYKUx4)

Comment: The ratio of the half octave interval would need to be the square root of $2$.  This is typically the first proof of irrationality that a maths student meets.

Comment: [Here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~mrubinst/tuning/12.html) is basically a text version of the video linked above.

Comment: @Ken I added an explanation of what the octave is.

Comment: To split the octave "equally" into $n$ parts, you need a rational number equal to $\root{n}\of2$, which is impossible.

Comment: Right, but that sort of skipped the proof, no? How do you know that is has to be $$\sqrt[n]{2}$$?

Comment: You should add an explanation of what "splitting" an octave means.  The major fifth vibrates at $\frac 32$ (660 Hz)  the lower and the higher vibrates and $\frac 43$ over it.  DId you mean a note where it vibrates at $x$ times 440Hz, an 880 and $x$ times it?  That would, as others point out require $x = \sqrt 2$.

Comment: "How do you know that is has to be
2–√n"  That's pretty much the definition of what you are talking about, isn't it.  You want a note that vibrates and $x$ times 440, and then if you vibrate again at $x\times x$ and then vibrate again at $x\times x\times x$ and you do this $n$ times it vibrates and 880.  If each note vibrates at $x$ times the previous note then the $n$th not vibrates and $x^n$ times the first note.  For that to be a full octave we need $x^n = 2$.  That's the parameter of the question.

Answer (score 1):

To prove a statement you must state it.

So....

> Definition:  A musical *interval* is two notes where the higher note vibrates at a set *frequency* rate faster than the lower one.

> An octave is an interval where the frequency rate is $2$.

Observation:  If you *compound* an interval upon itself so that you have a base lower note, and a second note that vibrates at the set frequency more than a note the vaibrates at a set frequency above the low note, this new interval has a frequency that is the original frequency squared.  That is to say if you have three notes: a base note $m$ a second note $n$ so that $m$ and $n$ is an interval of a frequency of $x$, and third note $u$ so that $n$ and $u$ is an interval of a frequency of $x$, then $m$ and $u$ is an interval of frequency $x^2$.

This should be clear as the vibration of $n$ is $x$ times the vibration of $m$, and the vibration of $u$ is $x$ times the vibration of $n$ then the vibration of $u$ is $x$ times $x$ times the vibration of $m$.  That is $x^2$ times the vibration of $m$.

If you repeat the procedure a positive integer $k$ times, the resulting interval will be an interval with a frequency of the original frequency to the $k$th power.

> Definition: An interval with a set frequency rate between $1$ and $2$ is said to *split an octave* if compounding the interval some positive integers of times creates an interval that is a positive integer of octaves.

> Claim:  There is no interval with rational frequency that splits the octave.

Pf:  Suppose we have an interval with a frequency of $x; 1< x < 2$, that when compounded $k$ times because an interval of $m$ octaves.

That means $x^k = 2^m$.  If $x$ is rational then there exist integers $a, b$ so that $x =\frac ab$ and $a$ and $b$ have now factors in common.  So $(\frac ab)^k = 2^m$.

So $\frac {a^k}{b^k} = 2^m$

So $a^k = 2^m b^k$.  This means $2$ is a factor of $a^k$ and therefore, because $2$ is prime, $2$ must be a factor of $a$.  Any other prime factor, $p$, of $a$ must be a prime factor of $2^mb^k$ but it can't be $2$ so it must be a prime factor of $b^k$ so it must be a factor of $b$.  But that's impossible as we assumed $a$ and $b$ had no factors in common.

So $a$ has no other prime factors but $2$.

Meanwhile any prime factor of $b$ must be factor of $a^k$ and thus of $a$.  But we assumed $a$ and $b$ had not factors in common.

So $b$ has no prime factors at all.  ANd $a$ has only $2$ as a prime factor.

So $b = 1$ and $a = 2^u$ for some positive integer $u$.  So that means $x = \frac ab = \frac {2^u}1 = 2^u$.  But then $x = 2^u \ge 2$.  So the interval of $x$ is not less than an octave.  In fact, $x$ must be $u$ octaves.

So no interval "splits an octave".

=========== old answer below =====

The major fifth vibrates and $\frac 32$.  And a major fourth ant $\frac 43$.

So a major fourth over a major fifth vibrates at $\frac 32\cdot \frac 43=2$ and forms an octave.

A major fifth over a major fifth vibrates at $\frac 32\cdot \frac 32 =\frac 94= 2\frac 14$ and is more than an octave.

The circle of fifths actually fails.  C to G to D to A to E to B to F sharp to C is 7 major fifths and it's supposed to be 4 octaves.  But it is actually $(\frac 32)^7 = \frac {2187}{128}=17\frac {11}{128}$ whereas 4 octaves are $2^4 = 16$.

Now to make a chord that vibrates at $x$ and have a chord above that vibrate and $x \times x$ and have that be a perfect octave is to have $x^2 =2$.  There is no rational frequency that does that.  (Although that *is* the frequency the news was broadcast on Futurama.....)

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ split up the octave in equal parts then from 440Hz to the middle would be a step of $x$ and from the middle to 880Hz would again be a step of $x$. So the doubling would be two consecutive steps of $x$, so $x \times x = x^2$, and we'd have $x^2 = 2$.

No rational number can satisfy this equation: suppose $\frac{p}{q}$ did, where $p,q$ are integers without a common divisor (so the fraction is in its lowest terms). Then $(\frac{p}{q})^2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}=2$ and so $2q^2 =p^2$. So $p^2$ is even (being $2q^2$) so $p$ is even and then $p^2$ is also disivible by $4$ so $q^2$ is even (divide $p^2=2q^2$ by two on both sides, and at least one factor $2$ remains in $\frac{p^2}{2}$) and so $q$ is even, but then we have a contradiction with $p$ and $q$ having no divisor in common... So $\frac{p}{q}$ cannot exist and $x$ with $x^2=2$ is irrational.